# How to find if an input string satisfies a specific condition (which in turn is specified as a string with AND/OR clauses inside)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, visual-studio-2013

I have a set of strings (let us call these as "condition strings") that I get from a database. These strings have parenthesis and are joined by AND or OR clauses.

Some examples of these strings ("condition strings") are :-

1. `pattern_1 = (mary sam route) AND (dance run fly)`
2. `pattern_2 = (birds AND fly) OR (athlete AND run)`

And then I get a set of input strings (like emails, etc.) and I want to see if the condition specified by the "condition strings" are satisfied by the input string. In other words, I want to write a function like `isConditionSatisfied(string, string)` which when called as `isConditionSatisfied(some_input_string, pattern_1)` would return me true if `some_input_string` satisfies the condition specified by `pattern_1` namely if the input string contains either of the words in `(mary sam route)` and it also contains either of the words in `(dance run fly)`.

Likewise `isConditionSatisfied(some_input_string, pattern_2)` should return me true if either of the following conditions is satisfied - (a) the input string has both the words `birds` and `fly` or (b) the input string has both the words `athlete` and `run`.

My question is - are there any libraries in C# that would enable to write my function `isConditionSatisfied(....)` most efficiently, without me needing to break up the "condition_strings" into tokens and then checking for AND/OR conditions in the input string. I have been exploring `string.contains()` and `Regex.IsMatch()` but I am not sure if either of them has the support to do this kind of a AND/OR checks in an input string.

Any suggestions on how to write the function `isConditionSatisfied` in the most efficient manner in C# and if there are any existing libraries that may make my life easier for this kind of a problem ?

Comment: Oon't know if there are any libraries that will help you out with this, but you can use `string.split()` with AND or OR and then compare the strings you get. Call the `isConditionSatisfied` recursively and figure out the logic of how that would work.

Comment: Will your condition strings always be of the form `(A) condition (B)` or could they be of any length and possibly nested (e.g. `(A AND NOT (B OR C) AND D AND ((E AND F) OR (G AND H)))`)? In the second case you will probably need a stack-based parser.

Comment: It is the latter - it could be any length and nested. I just completed the implementation and testing of this. In essence I convert the expression to postfix and then evaluate the postfix using Regex.IsMatch on each component. For both conversion to postfix as well as for the evaluation of the postfix I had to use a stack as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I implemented this was in two steps - (1) convert the expression to postfix and then (2) evaluate the postfix by using Regex.IsMatch on each word. For both conversion to postfix and evaluation of the postfix I had to use a stack.

Comment: If you post code or an example how you solved this I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:

1. Convert pattern string to proper regular expression string (you may
   even be able to achieve it with simple string replacements depending
   on the complexity of your grammar / rules)
2. Compare input string against constructed regexp pattern string

e.g.

```
public string convertToRegExp(string pattern)
{
   string result = pattern;
   result = Regex.Replace(result, <regexp pattern matching your syntax>, <proper regexp syntax pattern>); // convert spaces to |
   result = Regex.Replace(result, <regexp pattern matching your syntax>, <proper regexp syntax pattern>); // convert ANDs
   ... // convert other rules
   return result;
}

public bool isConditionSatisfied(string input, string pattern)
{
   string rePattern1 = convertToRegExp(pattern1);
   return Regex.IsMatch(input, rePattern1);
}
```